# Infopath 2007 form ID not working

Tags: 2007, infopath, error

I have a legacy Infopath solution(2007/Moss) created by someone else that's not working correctly.

There is an ID field that's supposed to display in the form during data entry - it displays NaN instead. When the form is submitted, it is supposed to save the ID as part of the form filename- That's not working either. Everything else about the form works correctly. When the form is opened, I get the error - 
"An error occurred accessing a data source.

An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server. Log ID:5566", which I have been unable to troubleshoot further.

I am currently at a loss as to want to look at next. If I 'design' the form in Infopath, all the data connection properties look as I expect them to. Typically the 5566 eventid corresponds to an authentication issue, but the user can submit the rest of the form correctly, so I don't see how that could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to turn off "automatically pull when form is opened" for the RetrieveIDs data source.